# Como saber o maior valor de um Array?

Tags: javascript, array, loop

Estou fazendo 1 calculadora que soma valores digitados pelo usuário e quando os valores das somas chegam em 1000 ou ultrapassam, o loop acaba.

Até aqui tudo bem, o problema é conseguir identificar o maior valor digitado pelo usuário

A cada vez que o loop gira coloquei para colocar o valor atual de `var = i` em um array de forma que todos os valores digitados pelo usuario se armazenem nele.

Ao fim todos os valores estarão dentro do array, mas como encontrar o maior deles?

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema, aceite-a. "A aceitação de uma resposta significa que você recebeu uma resposta que funcionou...". Você tem 6 perguntas e não marcou nenhuma - pode ter esquecido ou não ter entendido como funciona o SO, dê uma olhada na [DOC](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 23):

Em JS isso é bem simples:

```
Math.max.apply(null, meuArray );
```

**Exemplo de uso:**

```js
var meuArray= [0,12,13,2,1273,28,1];
var maior = Math.max.apply(null, meuArray );

document.getElementById( 'resultado' ).innerHTML = maior;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

O `apply` funciona como se você tivesse passado os valores do *array* como parâmetros da função `max`, e equivaleria a se digitar `Math.max(0,12,13,2...`. O primeiro parâmetro equivale ao escopo a ser usado na função, e neste caso, como é indiferente, passamos `null`, que representa o escopo global.

Se seu *array* tiver muito mais que um milhão de ítens, o que geralmente não é o caso, pode usar uma solução com *loop*.

**Solução alternativa: o *loop*.** (exemplo didático)

```
var maior = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
   if ( meuArray[i] > maior ) {
      maior = meuArray[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Como é possível usar apply no objeto Math se o apply não pertence ao objeto Math?

Comment: @ropbla9 O `apply` é método do `function`.

Comment: Entao, n é do Math :/

Comment: @ropbla9 tudo que é function "herda" o apply (senão não funcionaria o demo :) ).

Comment: Aliás, o que é bom, pois o apply serve pra praticamente tudo que usa vários parâmetros, e bem útil pra criar situações dinamicamente.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Preciso entender melhor esses conceitos de herança. Recomenda algum link?

Comment: @ropbla9 eu geralmente pesquiso na **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

Quando preciso saber o maior numero de uma array então faço um `.sort()`.

Por exemplo:

```
[4,3,6,9].sort(function(a, b){return b - a;})
```

retorna `[9, 6, 4, 3]`, aí só preciso ir buscar o primeiro elemento.
Ou seja:

```
var elMaximo = [4,3,6,9].sort(function(a, b){return b - a;})[0];
```

Comment: e se for um array de objetos e quero ordenar por um dos atributos? array[{id: 1, nome: 'Joao'}, {id: 2, nome: Maria}], como faria essa ordenação pelo id?

Comment: @i9oni9on em vez de `return b - a` seria `return b.id - a.id`

Answer (score 6):

Se já existe um ciclo que ocorre para a recepção dos números inseridos, acredito que poderias também resolver o problema da determinação do maior número criando uma variável que armazena sempre o maior valor dos números digitados.

**Exemplo** (supondo que estajas a utilizar um `do` `while`):

```
    ...
    var maior = 0;
    do
    {
       if (numeroInserido > maior ) {
          maior = numeroInserido;
       }    
       // aqui podes vai o código responsável pela soma e restante validação do limite
       // máximo do valor 1000        
    }while (...)
```

Nesta solução não será necessário armazenar o valores em um `array` para determinar o maior número digitado.

**Nota:** 
*Assumi que conservas os números em um array para poder posteriormente determinar o maior deles.*

Comment: Se ainda assim , a preferência for manter os valores no array, podes faze-lo neste mesmo ciclo, sem precisar utilizar dois.

Comment: Este é o método que eu gosto.

A melhor maneira de encontrar algo é não perdê-lo pela primeira vez.

Answer (score 3):

Pra achar o maior numero dentre um conjunto de variáveis você pode usar a função max de Math:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 25;
var c = 20;
maior = Math.max(a,b,c); 
console.log(maior) //25
```

Ela aceita múltiplos argumentos então você pode usar spread (...) para utilizar com arrays

```
var numeros = [1,2,5,200,89,5,50];
var maior = Math.max(...numeros);
console.log(maior) //200
```

como o nome diz, ele "espalha" o array transformando-o em vários argumentos separados

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/160641)

Comment: @hugocsl Agora está independente da resposta do Bacco, é isso que você quer dizer com _independente de mais informações de quem perguntou_?