# Pegar o menor valor e o maior valor de um array com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para pegar o menor valor e o maior valor do array separadamente com JavaScript e jQuery?

> var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];

O menor valor nesse caso e 444.9 e o maior 984.9.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como saber o maior valor de um Array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35202/como-saber-o-maior-valor-de-um-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A maneira mais simples seria assim:**

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var min = Math.min(...arr);
var max = Math.max(...arr);


console.log(min); // 444.9
console.log(max); // 984.9
```

---

As maneira mais "convencional" seria combinar o `.reduce()` com o [`Math.max|Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

Juntei também um `.map(Number)` porque tens strings e é melhor trabalhar com números (ainda que funcionasse sem isso).

O `Math.max` e o `Math.min` aceitam dois (ou mais) argumentos, e retornam o maior/menor. O `.reduce()` passa o valor anterior e o novo, o que encaixa perfeito.

**Para saber o máximo usando `.reduce()`:**

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var max = arr.map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
});

console.log(max); // 984.9
```

**Para saber o mínimo usando `.reduce()`:**

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var min = arr.map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.min(a, b);
});

console.log(min); // 444.9
```

Comment: resposta rápida e pratica...

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a utilizar a biblioteca [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). A lib é extramente pequena e tem diversos outros recursos muito úteis.

Seria apenas este código abaixo:

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
console.log(_.min(arr)); //444.9
console.log(_.max(arr)); //984.9
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Terá que converter as strings em números antes de fazer as comparações:

```js
var arr = ["885.9", "984.9", "444.9", "528.9", "528.9"];
var maior = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    menor = Infinity;

arr.forEach(function(item){
  if (Number(item) > maior) maior = item;
  if (Number(item) < menor) menor = item;
});

console.log(maior, menor)
```

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar o [Math.Max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) e o [Math.Min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) para pegar os valores, como é algo relativamente simples vou apenas apontar os links e deixar você estudar =]
[Esse também](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp)

Comment: Agradecemos sua vontade de colaborar com a comunidade, mas talvez seja interessante ler o texto [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/5878) O principal problema é que, se porventura, o link da resposta deixar de existir, a resposta perde o sentido por completo. Para contornar isso, verifique junto ao conteúdo do link os principais pontos que sejam válidos à pergunta e descreve-os aqui, mantendo o link apenas como um material de apoio.