# Revelar o valor boolean

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que verifica se os números passados nor argumentos são iguais, caso não sejam queria mostrar o maior número. Mas não sei como mostrar o maior....

```js
function igual(valor1, valor2) {
  if (valor1 === valor2) {
    console.log('São valores iguais')
  } else {
    let maior = valor1 > valor2 || valor1 < valor2
    return `O maior numero é: ${maior}`
  }
}
console.log(igual(5, 6)); // dá "true"...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na seguinte expressão:

```js
valor1 > valor2 || valor1 < valor2
```

Ela sempre irá avaliar um `true`, já que os operadores `>` ou `<` não retornam o maior número, mas sim um booleano, dependendo da comparação de maior que ou menor que, respectivamente.

Portanto, você deve restar a condição e retornar o número caso ela for verdadeira:

```js
function igual(valor1, valor2) {
  if (valor1 === valor2) {
    return 'Iguais.'
  } else {
    if (valor1 > valor2) {
      return valor1;
    } else {
      return valor2;
    }
  }
}

console.log(igual(5, 5));
console.log(igual(5, 6));
```

Você também pode utilizar uma única expressão utilizando um [operador ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional) para decidir qual é o menor número:

```js
function igual(valor1, valor2) {
  if (valor1 === valor2) {
    return 'Iguais.'
  } else {
    return valor1 > valor2 ? valor1 : valor2;
  }
}

console.log(igual(5, 5));
console.log(igual(5, 6));
```

Mas conforme mencionado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449223/69296), fazer com que uma função retorne dois tipos diferentes não é uma prática muito aconselhável. Talvez seja melhor você agrupá-los em um tipo de estrutura de dados:

```js
function igual(valor1, valor2) {
  if (valor1 === valor2) {
    return { equal: true, biggest: valor1 };
  } else {
    return {
      equal: false,
      biggest: valor1 > valor2 ? valor1 : valor2
    };
  }
}

console.log(igual(5, 5));
console.log(igual(5, 6));
```

Answer (score 3):

Para saber o numero maior podes usar o [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) (também descrito [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35204/129)), mas de maneira geral não aconselho a ter uma função que retorna ora Boolean ora numero... é melhor o resultado ter a mesma tipagem. Porém podes retornar dois valores ao estilo de Python.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```js
function igualEMaior(...valores) {
  const iguais = valores.every((val, i, arr) => arr[0] === val);
  return [iguais, Math.max(...valores)];
}

const [igualA, maiorA] = igualEMaior(4, 5, 6);
console.log(igualA, maiorA); // false 6

const [igualB, maiorB] = igualEMaior(4, 4, 4);
console.log(igualB, maiorB); // true 4
```